# call Python script from JavaEE

Tags: python, java

i create model using sklearn library and i want to run this model in JavaEE application i have been trying Jython, but it's impossible to import some important library like pandas and numpy, so how I can do to call a python script for JavaEE application.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably ask programming questions on StackOverflow as more people will be able to help you with this kind of problems. As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12738827/how-can-i-call-scikit-learn-classifiers-from-java), you can serialize scikit-learn model to PMML and then execute it using [jpmml-evaluator](https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-evaluator). There are different suggestions in that post, so you should take a look at it and see what works best for your use case.